# SSL errors on Heroku (Mixed contents)

Tags: 7

I have an app via Drupal 7 on Heroku. You know, myapp.herokuapp.com is default with SSL.

But when I try `https://myapp.herokuapp.com` get many errors in console like this:

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com/modules/system/system.base.css?ngonpd'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I tried to add this code in settings.php but not working:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) == 'on') {
  $base_url = 'https://myapp.herokuapp.com';
}
else {
  $base_url = 'http://myapp.herokuapp.com';
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

IMO `$base_url` in `settings.php` should work

Alternatively you can try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: $base_url works for me